# Save form as image (screenshot)

Tags: vb.net, forms, bitmap, controls, screenshot

I have 2 forms.

- Form 1 contains the content that i need a screenshot of
- Form 2 contains graphics drawing (this form is always on top but transparent).

I need to screen shot the first form without making it on top of form 2 as well as without including content from form 2.

here is some what i am working with, which i am trying to fix.

```
Private Function TakeScreenShot(ByVal Control As Control) As Bitmap
    Dim Screenshot As New Bitmap(Control.Width, Control.Height)
    Control.DrawToBitmap(Screenshot, New Rectangle(0, 0, Control.Width, Control.Height))
    Return Screenshot
End Function
```

This function is not working because Control.drawtoBitmap is not setting the value of IMG.

IMG is blank and being returned as a plain white image.

The calling of this function is this

```
TakeScreenShot(form1.webbrowser1).Save("c:\Screenshot.png", 
     System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

All help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

Replace your `TakeScreenShot` function with this:

```
Private Function TakeScreenShot(ByVal Control As Control) As Bitmap
    Dim tmpImg As New Bitmap(Control.Width, Control.Height)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(tmpImg)
        g.CopyFromScreen(Control.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0)), New Point(0, 0), New Size(Control.Width, Control.Height))
    End Using
    Return tmpImg
End Function
```

This should work, however if for some reason it doesn't the problem might be the transparent form on top.
You can call it in excactly the same way.
Good luck :)

Comment: If you want to capture not only the client portion of yout window, but all the window, just change g.CopyFormScreen instruction this way -> g.CopyFromScreen(Control.Location.X, Control.Location.Y, 0, 0, Control.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)