# Print Screen Shot of Program VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Is there anyway to print out a screen shot of my program? Like... when I press the print button, it will print out a screenshot of the program? I have attached a picture of how it looks... I have a regular print out, but need the screen shot as well.

Thanks in advance,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [PrintForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629268.aspx) component to your form:

[image]

Add a button with the following code:

```
Private Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
    PrintForm1.PrintAction = Printing.PrintAction.PrintToPrinter
    PrintForm1.Print()
End Sub
```

Done.

Comment: I don't see a "print form" button. I am using VS 2013 CE... What are you using?

Comment: @PaigeLee: I'm using 2010 Pro, the PowerPack is not included with 2013 but you can download it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488277.aspx).

Comment: -- so it works, yay! but it is printing in portrait vs landscape... any ideas? (I'm googling it just in case I can figure it out)

Comment: @PaigeLee: You can use `PrintForm1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True` to force landscape.

Answer (score 0):

[Save form as image (screenshot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676601/save-form-as-image-screenshot)

The above works.  I tried it, and had a slight issue with it capturing the full size of my form but starting below the title bar and extending beyond that.  you'd just need to change the new point to -X (X being the size of title bar and border of form).  That make sense?